# Angular Async Pipe ngFor throwing an error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to populate a dropdown (reactive form) via a JSON file in a server. For some reason it keep showing the error

> TestComponent.html:14 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for
>   pipe 'AsyncPipe'

here is how i set the value for my object in ngOninit()

```
  this.http.get(url).subscribe((data) => {
      for (const key in data) {
          this.NameData.push(data[key].Name)
      }
  })
```

Template code:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="nameType">Name Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="nameType" formControlName="nameType">
        <option *ngFor="let NType of NameData | async" [ngValue]="NType">{{NType}}</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It looks like `NameData` is a regular array? You shouldn't need `async` there.

Comment: I thought since NameData is receiving a value through an observer, async is needed. Apologies I'm new to javascript

Comment: You use `async` when you're binding to an observable directly. If you're binding to a regular array, assuming you've initialized it with `[]` or similar, you just use it normally, even if it gets updated by an observable later.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Thank you very much, one clarification, the JSON file i'm reading from the server could get considerably big. Is there a better implementation (or recommendation) to handle that scenario?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing all the details. Maybe see if there's some way you can filter it down? If it ends up being a problem, you should probably ask a separate question for it.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Makes sense, thank you.